# qualitative data in data envelopment analysis (DEA)

Tags: operations-research

I wish to use qualitative input to calculate efficiency using DEA model. For that I based the input on certain questions which were answered on 1-5 rating scale. each input has 5 such questions(attributes) to it. How can I use this rating to get a consolidated score for the input to apply DEA?

Answer (score 0):

When using qualitative variables (ordinal - Likart scale) first, you must convert qualitative data into a quantity where through the rank of the institution subject to evaluation DMU0 gives its input or output a value of X = 1 and Y = 1, while the other units whose order is less than the rank of the evaluation unit takes X = 1. Y= 0 As for the one whose rank is greater than the rank of the evaluation unit X = N and Y = 1 where N is the number of study units and thus all variables become a quantifiable amount

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.